# LibreOffice Snap package doesn't list the system printers

Tags: libreoffice, snap

I have installed on my system Ubuntu 16.04 the following version of LibreOffice snap: libreoffice 5.3.4.2 / 21 / canonical

The problem is that when I want to print a document, only a "Generic Printer" is listed. No one of the printers of my system is listed. So, I can't actually print anything. How can I setup the snap version of LibreOffice, so that it can "see" my printers?

Thank you

Comment: Cross-posted to https://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/132339/libreoffice-snap-package-doesnt-list-the-system-printers/.

Answer (score 3):

Use `snap connect libreoffice:cups-control :cups-control` [to get printers working in LibreOffice](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/libreoffice/+bug/1711186).

<sub>Please also say that you're affected by the bug I've linked (by clicking the button at the top of that page) and [like this post on the forum](https://forum.snapcraft.io/t/request-autoconnection-of-cups-control-for-libreoffice/2517) so that people don't have to run this command in the future.</sub>

Comment: this also fixes the issue with firefox