# Cannot Print from LibreOffice 7.5 Using Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: printing, libreoffice

I have a document in LibreOffice Writer format that I would like to print.  As I said in the title line, I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.2 and my version of LibreOffice is 7.5.2.2 (X86_64)/LibreOffice Community, which I believe was the version of LibreOffice included with Ubuntu 20.04.

My printer is set up in Ubuntu, that is, I can see it when I go to 'Settings'.  It is a network printer, and I know its local network IP, although I'm never prompted for it in the setup, or even when I administer CUPS.  It is a network printer, a Brother MFC-J485DW.

I'm able to print from other apps, such as Document Viewer.

When I go to File - Print in LibreOffice Writer, I'm am given the option of 'Generic Printer' or 'Print to File'.  The 'Generic Printer' option does not seem to be it, as I get the error message, "Could not start printer.  Please check your printer configuration."  As if that is much help.

I've researched and have seen this question posted before, in various forms.  The answer always seems to have something to do with CUPS.  The answers provided lead down paths that have to do with other distros of Linux, so they have to do with editing files that Ubuntu 20.04 does not have.

Could someone please explain to me in a cut and dry matter, without having me have to repeat what I have already provided above, a solution to this issue?

Comment: Sure, does this answer your question? [LibreOffice Snap package doesn't list the system printers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/958708/libreoffice-snap-package-doesnt-list-the-system-printers).

Comment: Oh, yes.  Now I can see my printer, although, it didn't print, but I'm sure I'm on the right track now.  So, like, how are we supposed to know something like this?  I just hate all of the fighting I have to do for Linux.  Got it to print just now, thank you!